# ¿Porque me sale este error ERR_UNSAFE_PORT?

Tags: web, servidor, xampp, chrome

[image: Imagen del error]

Me sale un error al abrir mi pagina web desde el explorador chrome, si la habro desde otro no tengo problemas.
Estoy usando Xampp
y estoy trabajando con el puerto 80
Alguna idea del porque?

Comment: Utilizo dyndns, por medio de una ipvirtual en forticliente dirijo el 123 al 80
esto es para que personas fuera de mi red puedan ver la pagina.
De todos modos, no puedo ver la pagina en chrome ni dentro de mi red, ni por fuera.

Comment: entiendo, mira googleando https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports

Comment: Si vi esa solucion, para verlo en mi pc si funciona, pero si tengo n numero de usurios, nimodo de hacerlo con todos jejeje
Deje la configuracion de xamp por default, hay alguna manera de evitarlo desde el servicio?

Comment: es que el problema de raiz es el puerto, desconozco las herramientas que estas utilizando, pero podrias cambiarlo?

Comment: No utilices el puerto 123, que es utilizado por NTP. Utiliza directamente el puerto 80 o algún otro puerto que no sea de un servicio conocido, y por tanto no considerado inseguro por chrome que, creeme, tiene buenas razones para hacer lo que hace. ¿Que tal el 8080?

Comment: No me deja  la plataforma seleccinar la respuesta o votarla, pero era el puerto 80, cambie al 8080 y funciono sin problemas. Gracias